# Expanding the generating function of the Fibonacci numbers to find a cute formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

$F_0=1$, $F_1=1$, $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$. The generating function is $-\frac{1}{x^2+x-1}$. I have to expand it to prove that $F_n=\sum_k\binom{k}{n-k}$. Could you help me please?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_k \binom{n-k}{k}$ for the sum?

Comment: @Mike: Those coincide for suitable ranges of $k$.

Comment: In fact in a sense the version in the question is nicer in that you can let $k$ run from $0$ to infinity.

Comment: @anon, joriki: Yes, you both are right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding as a geometric series and then using the Binomial Theorem, we obtain
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (x^2+x)^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{l=0}^k{k\choose l}x^{2l+(k-l)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k+l=n}{k\choose l}\right)x^n$$
Rewrite the inner sum's index $l=n-k$ so that equating coefficients with $\sum F_n x^n$ gives
$$F_n=\sum_{k} {k\choose n-k}.$$